# Double quotes in string

Tags: elixir

I have following shell statement:

```
gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(/Users/developer/Desktop/1449367569_Concurrency.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

and want to execute in elixir with the `system.cmd` function. I tried as follow:

```
System.cmd("gs", ["-q", "-dNODISPLAY", "-c \"(/Users/developer/Desktop/1449367569_Concurrency.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit\""])
```

But it does not work at all. The output is just nothing.

Comment: How about `System.cmd("gs", ["-q", "-dNODISPLAY", "-c", "(/Users/developer/Desktop/1449367569_Concurrency.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"])`?

Comment: Wow....How do you know that? I was searching for half a day. Thanks  so much.

Comment: Just posted an answer with explanation. Let me know if anything is still unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original command you posted, the shell will pass 4 arguments to `gs`:

```
-q
-dNODISPLAY
-c
(/Users/developer/Desktop/1449367569_Concurrency.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit
```

The double quote around `(/Users/developer/Desktop/1449367569_Concurrency.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit` is not passed to `gs`; it's just part of the shell's syntax, useful for when you want to include a space character in an argument. For example `echo "foo"` will print just `foo`, not `"foo"`.

So you need to split `-c` and the rest into separate strings, and not include the double quote in the last argument:

```
System.cmd("gs", ["-q", "-dNODISPLAY", "-c", "(/Users/developer/Desktop/1449367569_Concurrency.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"])
```